# SQL Server - Grant user read/update permissions on all databases, including future databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a user that can read and update any databases on the server (including later added databases), is there any permission on server level that would allow reading and updating but nothing more that that like ALTER

By looking on the available permission on server level  *sys.fn_builtin_permissions('SERVER')*   i don't see anything less than ALTER, is there really no way to do this?

Comment: No, `USER`s are database objects, so you can't create a `USER` at instance level that has specific permissions in *all* databases. You will need to create the `USER` in *every* database and assign it the relevant permissions. YOu might want to consider creating a `ROLE` in all your user database that it can be assigned to. If you want, you can also then create the `USER` and `ROLE` in the `model` database so that future created databases have the `USER` with the wanted permissions automatically.

Comment: @Larnu Yep that works, i created the user in the Model database with the db roles **datareader** and **datawriter** and it works perfectly - thanks

Comment: Now "add" that tidbit of information to your disaster recovery plan as well as to your configuration documentation for the next migration.